# d3 grouped bar chart inconsistent items alignment

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, bar-chart

I'm trying to align grouped bar chart items whether its a single item in the group or multiple items in the group it is always slightly off and not aligned properly. Items should always be on the middle of the group and align with a city name. I can position if data has multiple items within the group, however if data object has only one item per group or items amount differs per group the position is inconsistent. I believe  it could be something with the width of the bars itself? I need a bar always to be 3px but always to be centred.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-nash-jid36?file=/src/GroupedBarChart.js:2684-2703)

Expected layout:

[image: expected output]

What I've got:

[image: current output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chartHeight`, `itemWidth`, `barWidth`, `barMargin` to change bar layout:

```js
const chartData = [
  {
    id: "LONDON",
    values: [{value: 5000},{value: 4000},{value: 3000}]
  },
  {
    id: "TOKIO",
    values: [{value: 2000},{value: 3000},{value: 4500}]
  },
  {
    id: "LA",
    values: [{value: 2000},{value: 3000},{value: 4500}]
  },
  {
    id: "NY",
    values: [{value: 4000},{value: 2000},{value: 3500}]
  },
  {
    id: "PARIS",
    values: [{value: 2000},{value: 3000},{value: 4500}]
  },
  {
    id: "BARCELONA",
    values: [{value: 500},{value: 1500},{value: 1000}]
  }  
  
];

const colors = ['brown', 'red', 'orange'];
const chartHeight = 150;
const itemWidth = 100;
const barWidth = 20;
const barMargin = 2;
const xMargin = 50;
const yMargin = 20;

const createChart = (container, data)  => {
    const svg = container.append('svg')
    .attr('width', data.length * itemWidth + xMargin * 2)
    .attr('height', chartHeight + yMargin * 2);
    
  const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(d => d.id))
    .range([0, data.length * itemWidth]);
    
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
  
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${xMargin},${yMargin + chartHeight})`)
    .call(xAxis);

  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([5000, 0])
    .range([0, chartHeight]);
    
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);
  
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${xMargin},${yMargin})`)
    .call(yAxis);
   
  svg.selectAll('g.city')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('city', true)
    .attr('transform', d => `translate(${xMargin + xScale(d.id) + itemWidth / 2},${yMargin})`)
    .each(function(d) {
        const city = d3.select(this);
      for (let i = 0; i < d.values.length; i++) {
        const y = yScale(d.values[i].value);
        const height = yScale(0) - y;
        const x = (i - d.values.length / 2) * (barWidth + barMargin);
        city
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("width", barWidth)
          .attr("height", height)
          .style("fill", colors[i]);
      }
    });
   
} 

createChart(d3.select('#container-1'), chartData);

createChart(d3.select('#container-2'), chartData.slice(0, 2));
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 210px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-1" class="container"></div>

<div id="container-2" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but nothing has changed, if you open in full window mode it it still cont aligned https://imgur.com/a/5FyFRs5, also bars need to be 3px wide so width of each bar 3px https://imgur.com/a/IVYeKiR

Comment: You need to adjust all your margins and remove hard-coded positioning numbers. Bars and X axis use the same scale, but there are additional transforms that should be removed. I have removed the second x scale since it's redundant - please revise your code very carefully and remove all unecessary transforms.

Comment: I also notice that `width` from `useWindowWidthDimensions()` is not always a valid number (you can add  `useEffect(() => console.log("W: ", width), [width]);` and see it in the console)

Comment: One more thought: use a fixed width for a tick and set the SVG element width according to the number of items in your data. Set the SVG parent container scrollable if the graph needs more width than container's

Comment: number of items in my date is dynamic thus varies, also it should be working on multiple screen dimensions, thus I have to re-calculate width on window shrink/expand.

Comment: Exactly. You should change the size of SVG according to the number of items: if a width per item is 100 and you have 5 items and 25px margins at both sides, set the width to 550 (and so on). Also, set `overflow-x: auto` for the parent DIV

Comment: I'm trying to implement your approach but have some questions would you please be able to help https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232541/room-for-edgar-kiljak-and-michael-rovinsky?

Comment: Michael, I have a few questions regarding this implementation? Some bars go beyond the chart.

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian, Hi. Can you post a new question? I'll try to answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67669499/bars-are-going-beyond-the-chart-range-in-d3-bar-chart