# Bars are going beyond the chart range in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, bar-chart

Bars in the grouped bar chart positioned correctly across x axis, however even thought I have a pre-defined range some of the bars are always beyond the chart with some `y` value equals to e.g. enormous -31199600.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-yalow-zqx1z?file=/src/GroupedBarChart.js)

```
// chart dimensions
const height = 600;
const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#4FD8DD']);
const itemWidth = 140;
const barWidth = 3;
const barMargin = 5;
const xMargin = 80;
const yMargin = 150;

 const svg = svgEl
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'grouped-bar-chart')
      .attr('width', storeData.dataset.length * itemWidth + xMargin * 2)
      .attr('height', height);

    const xScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(storeData.dataset.map((d) => d.city))
      .range([0, storeData.dataset.length * itemWidth]);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([-120, height - 200]);

    yScale.domain([d3.max(storeData.dataset[0].values, (d) => d.value), 0]);

    // draw chart
    svg
      .selectAll('g.city')
      .data(storeData.dataset, (d) => d.city)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .classed('city', true)
      .attr(
        'transform',
        (d) =>
          `translate(${xMargin + xScale(d.city) + itemWidth / 2},${yMargin})`
      )
      .each(function (d) {
        const city = d3.select(this);
        for (let i = 0; i < d.values.length; i++) {
          const y = yScale(d.values[i].value);
          console.log(
            'yScale(d.values[i].value) --->',
            yScale(d.values[i].value)
          );
          console.log('yScale(0) --->', yScale(0));
          const height = yScale(0) - y;
          const x = (i - d.values.length / 2) * (barWidth + barMargin);
          city
            .append('rect')
            .attr('x', x)
            .attr('y', y)
            .attr('width', barWidth)
            .attr('height', height)
            .style('fill', colorScale(i));
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sets 5000 as the max value:

```
const maxValue = d3.max(storeData.dataset[0].values, (d) => d.value);
yScale.domain([maxValue, 0]);
```

Actually, max value is much higher (I get 400000000):

```
const maxValue = storeData.dataset.reduce((maxAll, item) => {
  return item.values.reduce((maxItem, val) => 
    Math.max(maxItem, val.value), maxAll);
}, 0);
    
console.log('MAX VALUE: ', maxValue);
```

Setting a correct value as `domain` upper limit for the `yScale` should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I'm a bit confused thought as I thought d3.max calculates the max value? What are the difference between Math.max and d3.max or reduce method is the key in this case?

Comment: Also getting ticks displayed weirdly https://imgur.com/a/XgpoUZ2, same ticks value being displayed multiple times

Comment: I think `d3.max` implemented with `reduce` and basically they both do the same: go over all values and find the maximum. In our case, `d3.max` will not work because we have array of objects containing arrays of values...

Comment: Yes, I see 1M is displayed twice

Comment: You have a problem in `yAxisTickFormat`. Try to fix it, and if it does not work, please post a new question

Comment: The problem is in yScale domain as if I revert it back it works fine.

Comment: I think you're wrong on it. The bug in tick format obviously exists, you just do not see it when the scale is limited to 5000 because it's seen only on high numbers.